# Проблема в создании директории внутри директории

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Нужно создать директорию внутри директории, чтоб это выглядело так:

[image: скриншот 1]

Но получается вот такое:

[image: скриншот 2]

Что не так я делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша IDE показывает директории в таком виде для компактности. Переключите режим просмотра дерева файлов из «Android» в режим «Project Files» и вы увидите полную структуру директорий.

Режим «Android»:

[image: скриншот 1]

Режим «Project Files»:

[image: скриншот 2]

Comment: спасли джуна, спасибо