# Откуда Gradle берет зависимости, из-за которых возникает конфликт версий?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle

Во время сборки Gradle получаю вот такой вот лог

```
Duplicate class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity found in modules androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime.jar (:androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0:) and androidx.activity.activity-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0)
```

Имя как будто одинаковое

И еще много, с разными именами сборок, например

```
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules androidx.annotation.annotation-1.5.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.5.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0)
```

Посмотрел зависимости в андроид студии, увидел такую картину

[image: annotation]

Выглядит так, будто конфликт между аннотацией 1.1.0 из appCompat и между 1.0.0 непонятно откуда. Но если посмотреть налево, то явно видно что у меня нет никакой аннотации версии 1.0.0, совершенно непонятно откуда оно его берет. Да и лог выше говорит о конфликте между 1.1.0 и 1.5.0, ни о каком 1.0.0 речи не идет. Почему механизм поиска зависимостей показывает что-то непонятное? Как мне найти нормальные зависимости?

Comment: "совершенно непонятно откуда оно его берет" -- чтобы посмотреть все дерево зависимостей, у gradle [есть команда](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html) `./gradlew app:dependencies`. С помощью этой команды вы можете понять, откуда какая зависимость берется.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan 1)Разве андроид студия через гуй не делает то же самое? 
2)Внутри проекта нет никакого исполняемого файла gradlew, вероятно пользуется какой-то из android SDK или еще откуда

Comment: При создании проекта у вас есть gradle wrapper, который лежит в самом проекте. Обычно исполняемые файлы лежат в корне проекта. Для linux это `./gradlew`, а для windows нужно использовать `gradlew.bat`. Если их там нет, то где-то в системе у вас может быть установлен просто `gradle`? Насчет гуи я мало что могу подсказать, наверное в гуи что-то похожее должно быть. Команда `gradlew.bat app:dependencies` бывает очень полезной для анализа зависимостей при разработке.

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan к сожалению, у меня макось( И нет, градла нет внутри папки которая открывается андроид студией, есть файл gradle-wrapper.properties,  в котором указано откуда градл брать, но самого его нет. 

Содержимое этого файла : 

`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip`

Кажется он скачивает его в папку wrapper/dists во время билда и потом удаляет

Comment: @VadikSirekanyan благодарю за наводку - в проекте я смог открыть терминал, написать там ./gradlew launcher:dependencies и студия подсветила сочетания клавиш для выполнения этой команды. Я по прежнему не знаю где оно берет градл, однако через прокладку студии оно срабатывает. Я получаю огромный лист зависимостей, однако это уже наверное тема отдельного вопроса. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы наверное смотрите файлы через Android Studio и там не видно этого файла. В Mac OSX тоже должен лежать файл `gradlew` в корне вашего проекта, посмотрите файл через Finder (либо в Android Studio [переключите режим просмотра файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1482720)). Да, конечно, задавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Ищите конфликт `lifecycle-*:2.0.0 <-> 2.1.0`, конфликт аннотаций уже следствие скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы посмотреть полное дерево зависимостей вашего проекта и проанализировать, откуда какая зависимость берется, выполните следующую команду из корня вашего проекта:

```bash
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Вместо `app` подставьте имя вашего модуля, если он другой.

Кроме этого, если вы хотите построить дерево всех зависимостей вашего билд-скрипта, то используйте эту команду:

```bash
./gradlew buildEnvironment
```

Об этих командах подробнее есть [в гайдах Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#listing_project_dependencies).